# Is there a way to determine which column causes error?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, parameters

I am working on a C# project that gathers data from different sources and stores the data in a SQL Server database. I sometimes get `String or binary data would be truncated.` error which is very annoying. I want to determine which column causes this error and log it. Is there another way than checking parameter lengths?

What I did is if the column is `varchar(50)`, checking if data length is greater than 50. I feel like this is like a walkaround and wonder if there is any other neat solution.

**Edit**

```
  if(data1.Length>50) logIt("col1, data1, condition");
    else if(data2.Length>80) logIt("col2, data2, condition");
else {
    SqlParameter p1 = (new SqlParameter("@p1", DbType.String));
                 p1.Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(data1) ? SqlString.Null : (object)data1;
                 s1.Parameters.Add(p1);

    SqlParameter p2 = (new SqlParameter("@p2", DbType.String));
                 p2.Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(data2) ? SqlString.Null : (object)data2;
                 s1.Parameters.Add(p2);

    s1.ExecuteNonQuery("UPDATE mytable SET col1=@p1,col2=@p2 WHERE condition=@condition");
    }


void logIt(string p){
     using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("log.txt"))
            {
              writer.WriteLine("Caused by:"+ p);
              writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
              writer.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
            }
            }
```

Comment: "Hang on, I'll get my crystal ball . . ." :) Sorry, but can you give us a code sample that re-produces the problem, and indicate the line and the error?. Without know what technologies you're using, and seeing how you're using them there's very little we can do to help. Thanks.

Comment: That is one of the most irritating error messages that SQL Server spits out - and no, I'm afraid, as far as I know, there's no "magic trick" to find out **which** column would be truncated - you'll have to do as you do - check each parameter value against a "known set" of acceptable maximum lengths ....

Comment: I added a summary of what it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would always check all of my parameters against the table that contains the data they will be used in. If the table says varchar (50) my parameter should be no longer than 50. I never write a stored proc without doing this and I presume you can simlarly limit parameter defintion on the c# side. Don't allow a user to type in more information than your table field can accept.

If you are pulling data from other databases or Excel spreadsheets, then you may have a differnt set of problems.

First you need to examine the incoming data carefully and determine if the column size you currently have is too small for the needed content. I find often when the data is too large, the information in the field is garbage and should be thrown out (things like notes about a contact being placed in the email field for instance instead of an email). You may even want to consider if you shoud be validating the input data in some fields.

If you need to keep the size and you aren't concerned about losing the extra characters, then you need to cast the data to the correct size before inserting it into your database or you need to create an exception process that will pull out the records which cannot be sent to the database into an exception table and return them to the people who own the orginal data to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, In one of the INSERT statements you are attempting to insert a too long string into a string (varchar (50)) column.

You have to increase the column size to 50+ or 100, to fix the issue. To find which column is causing this issue is put some logs or run SQL Profiler or Enable All exceptions from VS -> Debug Menu -> Exceptions (Check all exceptions).